# Вызов своего шорткода в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Сайт работает на основе Divi + WooCommerce. Мне нужно переделать обычную иконку корзины в мини корзину с выпадающим списком. Готовые решения не подошли, поэтому пришлось самому. Есть 100% рабочий код, который я пытаюсь вызвать через шорткод. Проблема в том, что код запускается и в целом работает, но "улетает" за пределы всех div-ов.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'puhelinfix_header_cart' ) ) {
function puhelinfix_header_cart() {
    $class = 'current-menu-item';
        ?>
    <ul id="site-header-cart" class="site-header-cart menu">
    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>">
        <?php puhelinfix_cart_link(); ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Cart', 'title=' ); ?>
    </li>
    </ul>
        <?php
}
}
add_shortcode('divi-mini-cart', 'puhelinfix_header_cart');

if ( ! function_exists( 'puhelinfix_cart_link' ) ) {
function puhelinfix_cart_link() {
    ?>
        <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'puhelinfix' ); ?>">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'puhelinfix' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) ); ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php

if ( ! function_exists( 'puhelinfix_cart_link_fragment' ) ) {
function puhelinfix_cart_link_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();
    puhelinfix_cart_link();
    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
}

if ( defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) && version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.3', '>=' ) ) {
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'puhelinfix_cart_link_fragment' );
} else {
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_fragments', 'puhelinfix_cart_link_fragment' );
}
```

Стрелкой указано, куда шорт добавлен и куда он "улетает".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шорткод не должен ничего выводить на экран. Он должен вернуть строку.

В начало функции вставьте

`ob_start();`

В конец

`return ob_get_clean();`